# get llvm CallInst's attributes via C API

Tags: llvm

How can I get a CallInst's attributes (including return value, parameters, function) via C API(version 3.9)?

I can find some api for Function attribute but cannot find any for CallInst, besides, for the given function:

```
declare noalias i8* @malloc(i64) #1
```

LLVMGetFunctionAttr returns 32, whereas noalias attribute should be 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For function attributes (not tested):

```
LLVMValueRef YourFunction = LLVMGetCalledValue(F);
// Index is your attribute's number, e.g. first one is 0
// Length is how many attributes are there in the #Index list
unsigned Length = LLVMGetAttributeCountAtIndex(YouFunction, Index));
LLVMAttributeRef *Array = malloc(sizeof(LLVMAttributeRef) * Length);
// Save list of attributes of #Index attr of function
LLVMGetAttributesAtIndex(YourFunction, Index, Array);
// So, for `declare noalias i8* @malloc(i64) !{ nounwind }`
// Array should be [nounwind] (array of one element)
```

Comment: The code works, but how could I inspect what Array exactly is?

Comment: @cgcgbcbc loop over those values and use `LLVMDumpValue` to dump them to stdin, for example

Answer (score 0):

Get called function: [getCalledFunction](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a0bcd4131e1a1d92215f5385b4e16cd2e)

Parameters passed to the called function: [getAttributes](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a39fed9e3fb9323a7eb73cb65409f5586) 
Return Value: You can use the call instruction object as the value of the call.

Comment: I need the attributes of these object, i.e. for the function the attribute is #1 which is something like #1 = "nounwind" and for the return value the attribute is noalias. Besides, it's easy to find these attributes via C++ api but  I need a pure C api solution